# XSLT - Combining 2 nodes with attributes into 1

Tags: xslt, svg

I have the following source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg width="800" height="600" xml:id="pg1">
    <g class="foreground">
        <text    transform="translate(163,90)
                 rotate(0.000,219.664,8.938) 
                 scale(1.000,1.000)" 
                 RotationPoint="(320.000000,240.000000)" 
                 xml:id="anno1"
                 visible="1"  editwidth="439.33" editheight="17.88" 
                 forcewidth="0" forceheight="0" language_direction="1" 
                 textdirection="0" theme_anno_style="0">
            <tspan    justification="left" 
                      line-spacing="1.00" prepara-spacing="1.00"
                      bullet="0">
                <tspan>
                    <tspan   fill="#000000" font-size="16.000"
                             font-family="Arial" 
                             char-transform="0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00"
                             textLength="439.33" y="14.48" x="0.00">
       It is not a book you can curl up at night with</tspan>
                </tspan>
            </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
<svg:page id="page0.svg">
    <svg:rect id="page0.svg_BG_Rect" fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="800.00" height="600.00"/>
        <svg:textarea fill="none" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="" font-size="0.00" x="163.00" y="90.00" width="483.26" height="19.66" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0,320,240)" id="anno1">
            <svg:tspan fill="#000000" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="16.00" id="para1" text-align="start">
                <svg:tspan fill="#000000" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="16.00">
                    <svg:tspan fill="#000000" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="Arial" font-size="16.00">
      <![CDATA[           It is not a book you can curl up at night with]]>
                    </svg:tspan>
                </svg:tspan>
            <svg:tbreak/>
        </svg:tspan>
    </svg:textarea>
</svg:page>
```

I am told this is best done using XSLT, but the example/tutorial I have seen show simple 1 to 1 transforms, that could probably be done using text search/replace (Ok, slight exaggeration).

The above is just one example, there are many more, but I could really do with a starter XSLT to give me a start.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Yes XSLT can be used to transform XML documents. However, it seems in this case that you also add a lot of information that is not present in the source document. You can hardcode it in XSLT but otherwise it cannot be autogenerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit ambiguous from your example what you want, as some of the attribute values have no clear origin and would need to be hardcoded or calculated somehow.

That said, I think the following solution gives you the structure you are after. (Note that it's missing the finer details, like number formatting.)

Given the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg width="800" height="600" xml:id="pg1">
    <g class="foreground">
        <text    transform="translate(163,90)
                 rotate(0.000,219.664,8.938) 
                 scale(1.000,1.000)" 
                 RotationPoint="(320.000000,240.000000)" 
                 xml:id="anno1"
                 visible="1"  editwidth="439.33" editheight="17.88" 
                 forcewidth="0" forceheight="0" language_direction="1" 
                 textdirection="0" theme_anno_style="0">
            <tspan    justification="left" 
                      line-spacing="1.00" prepara-spacing="1.00"
                      bullet="0">
                <tspan>
                    <tspan fill="#000000" font-size="16.000"
                             font-family="Arial" 
                             char-transform="0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00"
                             textLength="439.33" y="14.48" x="0.00">
              It is not a book you can curl up at night with
            </tspan>
                </tspan>
            </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This XSL stylesheet:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="svg:tspan" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- Get the fill attribute for svg:tspan from the innermost tspan element
      (i.e. the tspan element with no tspan children). -->
      <xsl:variable name="fill">
          <xsl:value-of select="//tspan[not(tspan)]/@fill"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- Get the font-family attribute for svg:tspan from the innermost tspan element. -->
      <xsl:variable name="font-family">
        <xsl:value-of select="//tspan[not(tspan)]/@font-family"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- Get the font-size attribute for svg:tspan from the innermost tspan element. -->
      <xsl:variable name="font-size">
        <xsl:value-of select="//tspan[not(tspan)]/@font-size"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <!-- Create the transform attribute by parsing the RotationPoint attribute of
      the text element. -->
      <xsl:variable name="transform">
      <xsl:text>translate(0,0) rotate(0,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-between">
        <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="//text/@RotationPoint"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="after" select=" '(' "/>
        <xsl:with-param name="before" select=" ',' "/>
      </xsl:call-template>    
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="substring-between">
        <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="//text/@RotationPoint"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="after" select=" ',' "/>
        <xsl:with-param name="before" select=" ')' "/>
      </xsl:call-template>    
      <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- A helper function to find the string between two strings. -->
  <xsl:template name="substring-between">
    <xsl:param name="substr"/>
    <xsl:param name="after"/>
    <xsl:param name="before"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($substr, $before), $after)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Create the svg:page and svg:rect elements. Attributes hard-coded when it's not clear where they come from. -->
  <xsl:template match="svg">
    <svg:page xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="page0.svg">
      <svg:rect id="page0.svg_BG_Rect" fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="{@width}" height="{@height}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </svg:rect>
    </svg:page>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Create the svg:textarea element. Attributes hardcoded when it's not clear where they come from. -->
  <xsl:template match="text">
    <svg:textarea fill="none" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="" font-size="0.00" x="163.00" y="90.00" width="{@editwidth}" height="{@editheight}" transform="{$transform}" id="{@xml:id}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </svg:textarea>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Change the tspan elements to svg:tspan elements, using attributes from the innermost tspan element (which were put into variables earlier). Only the outermost tspan element has the id and text-align attributes. -->
  <xsl:template match="tspan">
    <svg:tspan fill="{$fill}" font-weight="normal" font-stretch="normal" font-style="normal" font-family="{$font-family}" font-size="{$font-size}">
      <xsl:if test="not(parent::tspan)">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">para1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">start</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </svg:tspan>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs this XML:

```
<svg:page xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="page0.svg">
   <svg:rect id="page0.svg_BG_Rect"
             fill="#ffffff"
             x="0"
             y="0"
             width="800"
             height="600">
      <svg:textarea fill="none"
                    font-weight="normal"
                    font-stretch="normal"
                    font-style="normal"
                    font-family=""
                    font-size="0.00"
                    x="163.00"
                    y="90.00"
                    width="439.33"
                    height="17.88"
                    transform="translate(0,0) rotate(0,320.000000,240.000000)"
                    id="anno1">
         <svg:tspan fill="#000000"
                    font-weight="normal"
                    font-stretch="normal"
                    font-style="normal"
                    font-family="Arial"
                    font-size="16.000"
                    id="para1"
                    text-align="start">
            <svg:tspan fill="#000000"
                       font-weight="normal"
                       font-stretch="normal"
                       font-style="normal"
                       font-family="Arial"
                       font-size="16.000">
               <svg:tspan fill="#000000"
                          font-weight="normal"
                          font-stretch="normal"
                          font-style="normal"
                          font-family="Arial"
                          font-size="16.000"><![CDATA[
              It is not a book you can curl up at night with
            ]]></svg:tspan>
            </svg:tspan>
         </svg:tspan>
      </svg:textarea>
   </svg:rect>
</svg:page>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. This has given me a good base. I've tried applying this in a C# program though I must be doing something wrong as it isn't doing the transform. However I think that will be me being dumb.